# Does Android have a terminal like Window's Run?

Tags: terminal

I have often hated the idea of looking for apps among tons of glossy icons and running them that way. I wonder if there is a terminal capability in Android like that of Linux or Windows (Run window) for faster and more seasoned app access. Is such a thing in Android inherently?

Comment: Depends on your Android version & launcher, you can type the name of the app in Google Search Omnibox on the launcher. You have to allow Google to search apps when doing phone search though (on "Google Settings" app).

Comment: @AndrewT. I am using KitKat

Comment: It doesn't have a terminal built-in.  I use the same app that sameer linked.

Comment: Does it need root access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep there is [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)

You can use the following command to run apps

`am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n package/class_fullname`

Comment: Where should I enter the command?

Comment: Open the terminal emulator app and you can run the command

Comment: SecurityException: Permission Denial

Comment: @JasonStack, you need root access to launch apps using `am` command unless you're running Android 5.1.1 then only ADB would be fine too.

Comment: Saw this post accidentally three years after I asked the original question. I knew nothing of adb at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Termux. You can find it on Play Store. I find it better than Terminal Emulator because it has a rich repository from which you can download a lot of useful programs.
I had no idea what Bash Script, Unix, Linux commands were or how to use them. 
After playing with Termux for 1-2 years (in my own rithm and just with stuff I want curious about plus experimenting), I saw some advanced bash scripting videos on YouTube and I was like : Hey I knew that! Thank you Termux :)
Mainly you need root for a lot of the things (playing with system files), but you can do a lot of other things as well, without it. Finding duplicate files, listening to online radio, downloading videos, you can even play some text based games :) 
If you know terminal commands well (linux, unix, Android) you will soon discover that you know a bit of coding as well :D